# Unexpected result with h:dataGrid

Tags: jsf

The underlying code makes the look of two column table while there are four `panelGroup's`.

[image]

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="4" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">                     
        <h:panelGroup><h:outputText value="#{ph.currentProduct.brand} #{ph.currentProduct.model}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup><h:outputText value="#{ph.currentProduct.price} грн"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup>
            Наличие:
            <p:rating id="present" value="#{ph.currentProduct.present}" readonly="true" />
            <p:tooltip for="present" value="test" />
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:form id="buy_button" style="">
            <h:inputHidden value="#{ph.productId}" />
            <h:commandButton image="images/buy.png" action="#{ph.addToCart}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>                             
</h:panelGrid>
```

Why is it?

Comment: Rozerro, symptoms suggest you're not running the code you think you're running. Everything works fine for us when above piece of code is copypasted unmodified into a scratchpad project with everything set to bare defaults and most recent versions (except of broken text and images, but that's a different problem)

Comment: @BalusC well, I`ll check it once more. But do you recive 4 columns in ouput with this code?

Comment: @BalusC the problem was with one of the styles applied to outer id.

Comment: In the next question, post a real MCVE instead of an untested snippet. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info